# Using angualr4 how to get image file actual width and size with ngx-image-cropper and cropper x1,y1 and x2,y2 positions

Tags: angular

I am trying to get the origianl size, width and height of file image using ngx-image-cropper with angular4 and also how to get tht top left, bottom left, top right, bottom right coordinates of cropped image.

Comment: Not sure but the `imageCropped` event emitter emits the all the information of the image. Try logging the parameter of the event that you have bound to `imageCropped`

`<image-cropper
    [imageChangedEvent]="imageChangedEvent"
    [maintainAspectRatio]="true"
    [aspectRatio]="4 / 3"
    [resizeToWidth]="128"
    format="png"
    (imageCropped)="imageCropped($event)"
></image-cropper>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

im not sure if its this what you want but i got the current widht,height, x1, y1 setting the [cropper] input attribute

```
<image-cropper
      [imageChangedEvent]="imageChangedEvent"
      [maintainAspectRatio]="true"
      [aspectRatio]="2 / 1"
      [resizeToWidth]="192"
      [cropper] =" coordinates" //this get the current coordinates
      format="png"
      (imageCropped)="imageCropped($event)"
      (imageLoaded)="imageLoaded($event)"
      (loadImageFailed)="loadImageFailed()"
  ></image-cropper>
```

and in the .ts file you create a coordinate object, in this case the object name is coordinates

```
export class ImageHolderComponent implements OnInit {

  coordinates = {x:0} // object that saves the crop coordinates
}
```